# What happens if my domain expires - will the web hosting also be canceled?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, namecheap, hostgator

I currently have a website created with WordPress.
Domain name registered with `namecheap.com` and host plan with `hostgator.com`.
Both created on the 25th April last year (one year plan) and set to expire this month.

Now I want to create three more other websites. 
And I want this current website's domain name to expire.
The client does not want to renew the site so I decided to let it expire.
If their domain expires, what will happen to the contents, will they also be deleted automatically? if it does, that is fine.

So now that I will create the three new sites, I want to use the same host plan with HostGator and just renew that.

Basically, I want to renew the host plan, have the current website expired and deleted, and create the other three sites. Is this possible?

Comment: Most web hosting providers do not delete contents of websites if the domain expires, websites are usually still reachable at your username (e.g., `~username.server123.hostgator.com`), however that might depend on if the control panel is setup to be dependent on the domain or customer info. It's probably best if you just [contact](https://www.hostgator.com/contact) HostGator to ask.